# How to create a deb package that installs a series of files

Tags: package-management, deb

I would like to create a brand new deb package to install series of files.  If at all possible, I would like to untar the folder containing these files as part of the installation into a known folder location.  Failing that, some knowledge how to package the source folders and files would be very useful.

Question is - is this possible and if so - how?

Lets give an example:

`~/mypluginfolder/` contains the files `x`, `y`, a subfolder called `abc` and inside that another file called `z`.

I want to tar this folder: `tar -cvf myfiles.tar ~/mypluginfolder`

I presume my debian package would look like

```
myfiles.tar.gz
myfiles+ppafoss_0.1-1/
   myfiles.tar
   DEBIAN
      changelog, compat, control, install, rules source
```

Is it possible to somehow untar `myfiles.tar` to a known folder location for example

```
/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/
```

Thus the final result would be:

```
/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/mypluginfolder
/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/mypluginfolder\x
/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/mypluginfolder\y
/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/mypluginfolder\abc\z
```

If - presuming launchpad needs source, advice is sought as to where I should drop the source folders and files into the deb package structure.

---

This will eventually will become a series of individual launchpad PPA packages.

What I prefer (but may not be able to achieve...) is to keep my packaging to a minimum - create a series of packages from a template and adjust the bare minimum (changelog etc + the tar file/file & folder structure).

Comment: Um... why do you want a .deb to do the *tar extraction*? Why not just take the source code *from* the tar and create the deb from scratch with the source?

Comment: A possibility could be that you wget the tarball from another place, adobe-flash style.

Comment: @jrg, that downloads the .bin installer, not a tarball. adobe packaging style doesnt provide the source (its closed source). The concept, though, is still the same, download the code from elsewhere and then extract/install  (i'm being nit=picky here :P)

Comment: @LordofTime Same difference. ;p

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Below, I'm assuming that the source is open (e.g. Python scripts) which are therefore not bound to any architecture (e.g. amd64 or i386), hence "all". If you have some C source, you need to use `Architecture: amd64 i386` in your source `control` file.

---

#### creating package ready for Launchpad

> This will eventually will become a series of individual launchpad PPA packages.
>
> What I prefer (but may not be able to achieve...) is to keep my packaging to a minimum - create a series of packages from a template and adjust the bare minimum (changelog etc + the tar file).

Launchpad only accepts source packages, so create a `rules` that installs the files in the correct places. For convenience, I'll use [debhelper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/debhelper). The directory with your files should look like:

```
debian/changelog
debian/control
debian/rules
debian/compat
mypluginfolder/...
```

A `debian/copyright` file may also be useful for informing users about the licenses associated with the package. I don't think you need a `postinst` script since you only need to extract some files. `compat` should contain the debhelper compatilbility level, say "8". (please refer to [the manual page of debhelper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/debhelper) for more details)

The `changelog` file can be edited with the `dch` command, available from the `devscripts` package. The `rules` (using debhelper) should contain:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
override_dh_install:
    dh_install mypluginfolder/ /usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins
```

Make it executable using `chmod 755 debian/rules`. A source package can be build using `debuild -S`. Be sure to be in a directory named `<package-name>-<version>`. More information about the `override_` behavior and the `dh` command can be found on [its manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dh).

The [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) was very valuable for me to understand this, it's recommended reading. Example packaging can be found on https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ppa.

---

#### creating package from existing file tree

[`dpkg-deb -b`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg-deb) can be used for creating tarballs from an existing file tree. First, start with creating a directory that should be named after your package. I'll assume you want to name it `myplugin`, and put it in `/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/mypluginfolder`. In addition, create the `DEBIAN` directory (uppercase!) for storing package information:

```
mkdir -p myplugin/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/mypluginfolder
mkdir myplugin/DEBIAN
```

Copy over your files:

```
cp -r ~/mypluginsfolder myplugin/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins
```

Next, you'll need a so-called [*control*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/deb-control) file located at `myplugin/DEBIAN/control` which describes the package. The contents of such a file are put below:

```
Package: myplugin
Version: 1.0-1
Maintainer: You <whatever@contact.address>
Architecture: all
Description: plugins for Rhythmbox
 Longer description here
 .
 As you can see, new paragraph are split by a single dot,
 and lines have to be indented by one space.
```

Now, you can optionally verify the contents of your package. The next command lists the file and directory entries contents of `myplugin`:

```
find myplugin -ls
```

If you're satisfied, build the package in the current directory:

```
dpkg-deb -b myplugin .
```

A new file will appear, named like `<package>_<version>_<architecture>.deb` which is in this example `myplugin_1.0-1_all.deb`. You can use the `less` program to peek in the file. For example, `less myplugin_1.0-1_all.deb`.

Comment: +1 absolute genius - I bow to you sir.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this great help! Had some trouble with the control file though, in the end it worked, but don't ask me how ;)