# Building packages on Ubuntu 16.04 for Launchpad

Tags: package-management, launchpad, debuild

I would like to build and upload to Launchpad a simple package for Ubuntu 16.04. It is just a colour theme; it basically requires the creation of a new folder under `/usr/share/themes`. The `rules`file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
override_dh_install:
    dh_install Ambiance-LightDark-Blue/ /usr/share/themes
```

And `control` (note the fake e-mail):

```
Source: ambiance-lightdark-blue
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Luís de Sousa <luis@mail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0)
Standards-Version: 3.9.4
Homepage: https://github.com/ldesousa/Ambiance-LightDark-Blue 

Package: ambiance-lightdark-blue
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: A light dark theme for Ubuntu 16.04.
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 I used this [great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/146353/177437) to build packages for Launchpad. However, on Ubuntu 16.04 the same simple method fails with a strange message:

```
$ debuild -S
[...]
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b ambiance-lightdark-blue-0.1 gave error exit status 1
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S failed
```

How can this be made on Ubuntu 16.04?