# How to create a deb file which installs Valve's OpenVR Package on Ubuntu?

Tags: deb, packaging

**Ultimate Goal:** Add [ValveSoftware/OpenVR](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr) to a PPA so that it can be installed via

```
$ sudo apt-get install openvr
```

I'm assuming this means I need to create something like an `OpenVR.deb`.

**Attempt:** I have read the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) which gives an extremely broad overview of how to get started, but it seems to assume a lot of Debian knowledge.

I know that the ultimate build command to run on someone's system should be as follows:

```sh
installOpenVR() {
    cd /tmp
    git clone https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr.git openvr
    cd /tmp/openvr
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake ..
    make
    sudo make install
    sudo ldconfig # OpenVR's `make install` fails to run this on its own
}
```

This at least will depend on autotools and `cmake`, so that the `Depends:` field in the `control` file should be adjusted accordingly.

**Problem:** From here's it's not so clear how to proceed. How does one create (or begin to create) an `OpenVR.deb` for `apt` to consume?

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have a Debian package `control` file and at least a very simple Debian build `rules` Makefile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/146343/how-to-create-a-deb-package-that-installs-a-series-of-files